# Django: Dynamic model field definition

Tags: django, dynamic, model, field

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I have a model definition which is rather monotone, it includes fields for bins from 1 to 50.

For the proof of concept, I wrote it by hand, but there must be a better way to automate the model definition and to keep the code nice and tidy.

So far I did it the follow way:

```
class Bins(models.Model):
    p1 = models.DecimalField(_('bin 1'), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    p2 = models.DecimalField(_('bin 2'), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    p3 = models.DecimalField(_('bin 3'), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    ...
    p50 = ...
```

On the [Django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels), I found a summary for dynamic model definitions, but its seems that it does not allow for loops in the definition:

I have tried the code below, but I get an error msg that MAX_BIN = 2 is an invalid syntax.
I understand the error that I can't iterated over the field like I tried.

```
Bins = type('Bins', (models.Model,), {     
    MAX_BIN = 50
    for i in range(MAX_BIN):
        name_sects = ["p", str(i)]
        "".join(name_sects): model.DecimalField(_("".join([bin ', str(i)])),
                             max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    })
```

**Is such a dynamic class definition generally possible?
If so, what is the best way to define the class?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What about just creating a new `Bin` model that has the # and points back to the `Bins` model?

Comment: this module is good for dynamic models http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dynamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your current edition, your loop is inside the definition of a dict. that's not allowed. however, you could define your fields in a dict outside your call to `type` which works fine. something like

```
attrs = {
    other_field = models.IntegerField(),
    '__module__': 'myapp.models',
}

MAX_BIN = 50
   for i in range(MAX_BIN):
       name_sects = ["p", str(i)]
        attrs["".join(name_sects)] = model.DecimalField(_("".join(['bin ', str(i)])),
            max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

Bins = type('Bins', (models.Model,), attrs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the code seems to solve the problem, but when I execute it, I get the follow error msg: "KeyError: 'myapp.model'" (I have changed 'myapp' to the name of my model). What is the reason for the error?

Comment: `myapp` is the name of your app, is it in `installed_apps`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I forgot to mention the folder as it is stated in the settings.py: apps.myapp.models. Thank you for your answer! Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that solves the same issue:

```
class Bins(models.Model):
    MAX_BIN = 50
    for i in xrange(1, MAX_BIN + 1):
        vars()['p' + str(i)] = models.DecimalField('bin ' + str(i),
            max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```