# How to stay DRY with Django model field definitions

Tags: python, django, django-models, models, dry

What is the best practice for observing DRY principles while defining Django model fields.

## Scenario 1:

```
file_one = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
file_two = models.FilePathField()
file_three = models.FilePathField()
```

Can I do this:

```
file_one = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
file_two = file_one
...
```

## Scenario 2:

```
base = models.FilePathField(allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
file_one = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH1)
file_two = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH2)
file_three = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH3)
```

How can I have file_one, _two and _three inherit/extend the rules in `base = models...` while being able to assign each a different `path=...`

I feel like [Django: Dynamic model field definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276046/django-dynamic-model-field-definition) is close but not quite what I'm looking for!

Stay awesome Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Pete that you definitely don't want to get too tricksy with a simple model definition. You could make the multiple nearly-the-same file fields a little easier to manage and still be explicit by keeping your defaults in a dictionary and using the ** operator. Something like:

```
filefield_defaults = {
    'allow_files':True, 
    'allow_folders':True, 
    'recursive':True
}

file_one = models.FilePathField(
    path=FIELD_PATH1,
    **filefield_defaults
)

file_two = models.FilePathField(
    path=FIELD_PATH2,
    **filefield_defaults
)
```

Comment: +1 for the advice, and a U+2713 for an answer to my question :)

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, DRY code is important and should be strived for, but there are limits :) In this case you're at odds between DRY and line two of the zen of python `Explicit is better than implicit`. If I was maintaining  your code I'd much rather come in and see:

```
file_one = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH1, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
file_two = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH2, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
file_three = models.FilePathField(path=FIELD_PATH3, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True, recursive=True)
```

Because while not being "DRY", it is immediately obvious what is going on, and I don't have to waste time going "wait, what?"

(Actually strictly speaking what I'd like to see is:

```
# Useful comments
file_one = models.FilePathField(
    path=FIELD_PATH1,
    allow_files=True,
    allow_folders=True,
    recursive=True
)

# Useful comments
file_two = models.FilePathField(
    path=FIELD_PATH2,
    allow_files=True,
    allow_folders=True,
    recursive=True
)
```

.. but that's because I'm a stickler for PEP8!) :)

Comment: +1 for the philosophy, but since Kip answered my question... :p